# Deep copy of class having a weak optional variable

Tags: ios, swift, tree, deep-copy

I am using a class named A to create a tree data structure. The class has a parent and an array of childs. I have marked the parent variable as weak in order to avoid strong reference cycles. Following is the class structure

```
class A {
 var child: [A] = []
 weak var parent: A?
}
```

I am also creating a deep copy of the above class for a specific use case using NSCopying protocol . However, in the deep copied object, even after setting the parent, it is becoming nil.

```
extension A: NSCopying {
 func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
  let copy = A(child: [], parent: nil)
  return copy
 }

 var copyOfChildObject: A {
   var childObject: A?
   
  //In here, I create a deep copy of the parent using copy() method.

  //Then, Iterate over the childs array of the parent and create a copy of each child and append each of them to a childs array

  //**Next, assign the deep copied parent to each deep copied child. Here, the parent is set to all the childs including the specific child that I want to access**.

  //Next, assign the childs array to the child property of the parent

  //Finally, I return the specific child

   return childObject
 }
}
```

When I access the copyOfObject.parent, it returns nil.

How can I avoid the parent from becoming nil ?

**Edit**:

```
extension A: NSCopying {
 func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
  let copy = A(child: [], parent: parent?.copy() as? A)
  return copy
 }
}
```

Earlier I was creating a copy and then setting the parent manually inside the copyOfChildObject property.

Now, I am setting a copy of the parent (because the parent is a reference type) inside the copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) method.

Still on accessing the copyOfChildObject.parent, it returns nil.

**Edit 2**:

Updating the logic of creating a copy of the child object

```
extension A: NSCopying {
 func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
  let copy = A(child: [], parent: nil)
  return copy
 }

 var copyOfChildObject: A {
   var childObject: A?

   //Here, root is the parent of the hierarchy. I have not included the 
   //calculation of the root but it is working fine

   createCopy(data: root)

   return childObject

   func createCopy(data: A, dataCopyParent: A? = nil) {
    //Here, I create a deep copy of the parent using copy() method

    let dataCopy = data.copy() as! A

    if let dataCopyParent = dataCopyParent {
     dataCopy.parent = dataCopyParent
     if !dataCopyParent.childs.contains(dataCopy) {
      dataCopyParent.childs.append(dataCopy)
     }
    }

    if dataCopy == self {
 
    //Set the required child if found here

    childObject = dataCopy
    }

   //Then, Iterate over the childs array of the parent and create a 
   //copy of each child and append each of them to a childrenCopy array

    var childrenCopy = [A]()
    for child in data.childs {
     let childCopy = child.copy() as! A
   
     if childCopy == self {
  
      //Set the required child if found here

      childObject = childCopy
     }

     //Next, assign the deep copied parent to each deep copied child. 
     //Here, the parent is set to all the childs including the specific 
     //child that I want to access

     childCopy.parent = dataCopy
     childrenCopy.append(childCopy)

     for children in child.childs {
      createCopy(data: children, dataCopyParent: childCopy)
     }
  
     //Next, assign the childrenCopy array to the childs property of 
     //the parent

     dataCopy.childs = childrenCopy
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This needs a [mre]

Comment: Only use `NSCopying` if you're using an old Obj-C API which requires you to conform to it. In pure Swift code though, I'd suggest simply implementing copying by hand and not relying on `NSCopying` at all.

Comment: Where do you actually set the parent? `A(child: [], parent: nil)` isn't copying anything at all.

Comment: @Alexander, I tried refactoring using your suggestion. But, I am still facing the same issue. I have posted the edited version above. Let me know if you have any suggestions on this. The catch here is that the parent is a weak reference.

Comment: The weak reference is a bit of a red herring. There's nothing special about it, it's just another property you have to set. The steps you layout in the comments of `copyOfChildObject` are exactly what you need, but you haven't shown us the actual code of `copyOfChildObject`.

Comment: @Alexander, I have updated the logic of creating the `copyOfChildObject`. It is because of this logic that I am setting the parent to nil and child to an empty array in the `copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil)` method. I am setting the parent and child array through this logic.

Comment: Making a deep copy of a node N in a tree data structure results in a newly allocated tree that is a copy of the subtree rooted in N in the original tree. This means that the node corresponding to N in the copy has its parent set to nil, which is expected since that node is the root of the copy. In this context, what is copyOfChildObject supposed to solve, what does the copyOfChildObject var mean for an arbitrary instance of type A?

Comment: Hey @user16016486, I'll take a closer look and try to make sense of this. There's a few odd things. I put my responses in numbered comments in this gist: https://gist.github.com/amomchilov/126d0b6495162a24c12cb1614f320c96

Answer (score 1):

The `weak`ness of the variable is actually of very little consequence. The overall idea to copying these objects is no different than any copying any other object graph. The fact that this is a cyclic object graph (i.e. that it's not just parents pointing to children, but also children refer to parents) means that you just need to modify these objects after they're made, to set their parent.

Below I show how I would do this. I annotated it with comments for your understanding, but they're really verbose, so of course, don't put those in your app.

```swift
class Node { // Renamed from "A", which isn't a descriptive/valuable name
    // Presumably these trees exist to store some value (otherwise why do they exist?),
    // so I add this value which lets me more easily distinguish one Node from another.
    public let value: String
    
    // Arrays store a plurality of things, so the name should be plural "children",
    // not just "child"
    public let children: [Node]
    
    // `parent` shouldn't be publicly settable. 
    private(set) weak var parent: Node? 
    
    public init(_ value: String, children: [Node] = []) {
        self.value = value
        self.children = children
        
        for child in children {
            // This new node (`self`) should own all these children.
            child.parent = self
        }
    }
    
    deinit {
        // Just adding this to show when the original tree nodes get deallocated.
        print("Deallocated \(self)")
    }
    
    public func deepCopied() -> Node {
        // This is all you really need. Create a new Node with the same value
        // as self, and a new array of children containing copies of all the children of self.
        // The init will automatically set the parent of all these new children.
        return Node(
            self.value,
            children: self.children.map { $0.deepCopied() }
        )
    }
}

extension Node: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    var debugDescription: String {
        "Node(\"\(self.value)\") @ \(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())"
    }
}



let copiedTree = {
    // Example tree:
    //      A
    //    /   \
    //   B     C
    //  / \   / \
    // D   E F   G
    let originalTree = Node("A", children: [
        Node("B", children: [
            Node("D"),
            Node("E"),
        ]),
        Node("C", children: [
            Node("F"),
            Node("G"),
        ]),
    ])
    
    // Print the originalTree and its objects' addresses.
    dump(originalTree)
    
    // Deep copy the tree, assigning it to `copiedTree`
    return originalTree.deepCopied()
}() // Notice that when this closure finishes, all the original nodes deinit

// ... but the copied tree nodes are still here, proving that they're a
// fully independent deep copy of the original

// Print the copiedTree, and note that its objects are at distinct addresses from
// those of the originalTree.
dump(copiedTree)
```

Notice that I don't use `NSCopying` at all. Most likely, you didn't really need it, and it was just a red herring all along. If you really did need a conformance to `NSCopying`, just add it with an extension:

```swift
extension Node: NSCopying {
    func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
        deepCopied()
    }
}
```

`NSCopying` was designed for Objective-C, which was much less strictly typed. It's not as ergnomic in Swift, where the result is `Any` and you need to cast it to do anything useful with it. This inconveinece is why I designed  `deepCopied() -> Node` as the API meant to be used from Swift in general, and `NSCopying` delegates to it. You did it the other way around (where `createCopy` delegates to `NSCopying`), which you noticed is a bit more cumbersome because you needed to use `as! A` a few times

Comment: Hey @Alexander, Thank you for such a detailed explanation. Helped me in identifying the odd things. I have one related question though. In my case, I need the deep copy of only a child of the tree. (Example: I need deep copy of only child B or C). The above deepCopied() method can give me a deep copy of B and its children, but when I access the parent of B (which is A) to create its deep copy, I get nil.  I am assuming that this might be happening because the parent (which is A) is a weak property. Am I correct here ?

Comment: "I am assuming that this might be happening because the parent (which is A) is a weak property." Nope. The weakness has nothign to do with it. When you call `nodeB.deepCopy()`, that's calling the `Node` initializer, which sets value, children and the `parent` property of the children, but not the parent of what is a new root node. In a doubly linked list, or a tree like this with back references, it's not valid to copy just a sublist (or subtree, in this case) without copying parent. Consider: your `nodeBCopy` would say its parent is `nodeA`, but `nodeA` wouldn't have it in its children.

Comment: Thank you Alexander. This explanation helped me clear my doubts.